# How to add users with email only in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subscribe

I would like my users to be able to 'subscribe' by only providing an email address without forcing them to sign-up with a password unless they want to.

I can add my own validation settings to allow this but i suspect it will interfere with the way the rest of Devise works if i start adding users without passwords or flagging them with my own 'non-registered' field.

At the moment the easiest solution seems to put these users in a different table but that has a bit of a smell about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

I have an app that does something similar - we use Open ID and OAuth exclusively for logins, and while we store the user's email address (Google Account or Facebook sends it back during authentication) they never login using it and so don't have/need a password.

This is a callback for what happens when a user signs up via Facebook:

```
  User.create!( :facebook_id => access_token['uid'],
                :email => data["email"], 
                :name => data["name"], 
                :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
```

The `Devise.friendly_token[...]` just generates a random 20 character password for the user, and we are using our default User model with devise just fine.  Just setting the password in a similar way on your users would be my approach, since you are never going to use their password.  Also, if you ever change your mind and want them to be able to login, you can just change a user's password in the database and build a login form, and devise will take care of the rest.

Comment: hat tip, I really like this solution

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach which I will attempt. However, I intend to offer both subscribe (email only) and sign-up (email and password). If i have a user that subscribes and I set the password to this token I assume that devise will treat this user as a signed-up user so will require the user to confirm their identity via email which may be a bit confusing to a user that has previously only subscribed with their email address.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify that.. If i have a user that subscribes and I set the password to this token I assume that devise will treat this user as a signed-up user so will require the user to confirm their identity via email _when they attempt to sign-up_.

Comment: I have implemented this and it gets me moving, however, I think i need to implement a subscriber_only flag in the user table which the create controller would use to establish whether the user is really signed-up or just a 'subscriber'. I had a poke around in the devise code and decided I could live with this for the time being and will revisit this later. Thanks Brett.

Comment: HOw can we ensure that the password generated (while creating the user) is unique every time . is there a way to pass a salt (say email) and ensure that the passwords generated are unique

Comment: The [`friendly_token`](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise.friendly_token) method uses [SecureRandom.base64](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) - if you do not trust that this library implements it as truly random, you will have to write your own.  Also please note that random `!=` unique - there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Another option further to Brett's answer is to override the password_required? method on the User model.

```
def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
end
```

If you store more than one omniauth provider then something like this should also work.

```
def password_required?
    super && self.omniauth_credentials.empty?
end
```

Full credit to Ryan Bates' railscast on Devise and Omniauth for this solution:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised